# Why wont my dynamically created ImageButtons show up in fragment?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a small problem. I got the dynamic creation of my TableLayout working but it won't show up.

This is my fragment XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/resourcesAvailableTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >

</TableLayout>
```

When the spinner gets changed it calls

```
onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

And that's where I fill up my TableLayout accordingly. Here's how I fill it up.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    quickVesselRef = optimizer.Reference.vesselAlloys;
    //I destroy the buttons and TableRows that were displayed previously
    if (oreButtons != null){
        availableRes.removeAllViews();
    }
    int[] imageRef = quickVesselRef[position].getCombinedOreResVessel();
    oreButtons = new ImageButton[imageRef.length];

    //create rows
    oreRows = new TableRow[(int)  Math.ceil(oreButtons.length /((screenWidth / (double)(buttonSize + padding))))];
    for(int i = 0; i < oreRows.length; i++){
        oreRows[i] = new TableRow(getActivity());
        availableRes.addView(oreRows[i]);
    }

    //create j buttons per i rows
    int buttonsPerRow = screenWidth / (buttonSize + padding);
    for (int i = 0; i < oreRows.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < buttonsPerRow; j++){
            if (i * buttonsPerRow + j >= imageRef.length)
                break;
            ImageButton button = new ImageButton(getActivity());
            oreButtons[i * buttonsPerRow + j] = button;
            button.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(buttonSize, buttonSize));
            button.setImageResource(imageRef[i * buttonsPerRow + j]);
            oreRows[i].addView(button);
        }
    }
}
```

where my TableLayout is called:

```
availableRes
```

This code doesn't crash, but it doesn't show the TableLayout that I created and I have no idea why.

Comment: what value of `oreRows.length` in your loop `for(int i = 0; i < oreRows.length; i++)`?

Comment: @Eldar Mensutov I have checked all the values. Lets say that I have 16 buttons to get displayed. On my phone that would be 13 buttons per row so there must be 2 rows. I also checked it and it is indeed 2 rows. All the buttons are created on the correct row and in correct amount.

Comment: Make sure that the `LayoutParams` used in `button.setLayoutParams()` are `TableRow.LayoutParams`.

Comment: But TableRow params only support modifiers like match_parent or wrap_content. I want my buttons to have width and height of buttonSize = 48dp

Comment: `TableRow.LayoutParams(int w, int h) - Sets the child width and the child height.` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html